# NSPredicate on array of dictionaries iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

How to filter an array of dictionaries with `NSPredicate` based on `key` of a dictionary inside another dictionary(which is inside an array), here is my response.

```
[
     {
         "_id" =     {
               "$id" = 53e28497e37c70d83021c830;
         };
         access = public;
     },
     {
         "_id" =     {
               "$id" = 53e28497e37c70d83021c839;
         };
         access = public;
      }
]
```

Now I need to filter this array based on the key `$id`. I tried different predicate formats to filter this array but no luck.How can I get dictionary object which matches `$id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this,

```
NSArray *filtered = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.id.%K == '1'",@"$id"]];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but app crashing at `NSArray* res = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];` predicate is `_id.$id == "53e28497e37c70d83021c839"`

Comment: here problem with literal string ,change $id key with any string and check it'l work

Comment: small edit in your answer `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.%K.%K == '53e28497e37c70d83021c830'",@"_id",@"$id"]` worked me. Accepted and up voted.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* filter = @"53e28497e37c70d83021c839";    
NSArray* res = [originArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K LIKE[c] %@", @"_id.$id", filter]];
```